# AppBar iconElementRight admin-on-rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm using example from https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Theming.html#using-a-custom-layout.

Added a new IconMenu as in the snippet below.  The right menu icon does not get displayed.  Tested component by invoking it from a different form, and it works.  However, integrating it into AppBar does not work.

Looks like either the styles or something else is interfering with it.

Has anyone got such a menu working well with AppLayout customizations?

```js
const styles = {
    // Snipped rest of the styles from example
    loader: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 50,
        margin: 16,
        zIndex: 1200,
    },

    iconMenu: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        margin: 16,
        zIndex: 1200,
    },
};

const AppBarMenu = (props) => (
    <IconMenu {...props}
        iconButtonElement={
            <IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
        }
        targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
        anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
    >
        <MenuItem primaryText="Settings" />
        <MenuItem primaryText="About" />
        <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
    </IconMenu>
);

AppBarMenu.muiName = 'IconMenu';

<AppBar title={title} iconElementRight={<AppBarMenu style={styles.iconMenu} />} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Used proposal in https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/525

Quote from above URL:
If anyone wants buttons in the title bar, they will have to have not only a custom layout, but copy AppBar.js from admin-on-rest into their project and import that. Inside AppBar.js, iconElementRight works inside the MuiAppBar tags, but not inside Layout.js.